# How do named and unnamed PCRE capturing groups interact?

Tags: regex, pcre

If the regular expression is e.g. `^(?<object>[\-\w]+)/([\-\w]+)$`, will one invoke the second capturing group as `$2` or as `$1`? In other words, are anonymous capturing groups absolutely or relatively numbered?

Answer (score 3):

Use `$2` to refer to the second *numbered* capturing group. Note I would not call it anonymous, maybe, "unnamed" would suit better here.

See a [sample regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4rXoiw/1).

[image]

See [PCRE docs](https://pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> PCRE supports the use of named as well as numbered capturing  parentheses.  The names are just an additional way of identifying the parentheses, which still acquire numbers.

Comment: So the names become synonyms for the corresponding numbers. Thanks, that's what I was trying to find out.

On a different note, anonymous and unnamed are synonyms, so I beg to differ. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In PCRE, Capture groups are numbered sequentially in the order found.

Here is an example where the groups are annotated, indented and numbered (mixed with some conditionals).

```
     # ==============================
     # Variations of the same thing
     # ==============================

1    ( a )?
2    ( b )?
3    ( c )?
c    (?(1)
       |  
   c      (?(2)
            |  
      c        (?(3) | (*FAIL) )
          )
     )

     # ==============================

4    (
  5       ( a )?
  6       ( b )?
  7       ( c )?
4    )
c    (?(2)
       |  
   c      (?(3)
            |  
      c        (?(4) | (*FAIL) )
          )
     )

     # ==============================

8    (?<A> a )?
9    (?<B> b )?
10   (?<C> c )?
c    (?(<A>)
       |  
   c      (?(<B>)
            |  
      c        (?(<C>) | (*FAIL) )
          )
     )

     # ==============================

11   (?<M>
  12      (?<A> a )?
  13      (?<B> b )?
  14      (?<C> c )?
c         (?(<A>)
            |  
   c           (?(<B>)
                 |  
      c             (?(<C>) | (*FAIL) )
               )
          )
11   )

     # ==============================
```

The *Branch Reset* treats conditionals a little differently.
At the next group number where the BR starts, it numbers sequentially
at the start of each branch.
Going past the BR, the numbering starts 1+ after the largest count assigned
from a single branch.

Example:

```
     # Super Branch with Conditional's

1    ( a )                     # (1)
     (?|
          x
br 2      ( y )                     # (2)
          z
          (?|
   br 3        ( u )                     # (3)
      4        ( u )                     # (4)
c              (?(1)
      5             ( R )                     # (5)
                 |  (?|
      br 6               ( x )                     # (6)
                      |  
      br 6               ( x )                     # (6)
   c                     (?(2)
                              a
                           |  
         7                    ( b )                     # (7)
                         )
         8               ( c )                     # (8)
                    )
               )
      9        ( u )                     # (9)
      10       ( u )                     # (10)
            |  
   br 3        ( e )                     # (3)
      4        ( e )                     # (4)
      5        ( e )                     # (5)
            |  
   br 3        ( c )                     # (3)
          )
   11     ( K )                     # (11)
       |  
br 2      (                         # (2 start)
               p
     3         (                         # (3 start)
                    q
                    (?|
       br 4              ( M )                     # (4)
          5              ( M )                     # (5)
          6              ( M )                     # (6)
          7              ( M )                     # (7)
                         (?|
          br 8                ( T )                     # (8)
             9                ( T )                     # (9)
             10               ( T )                     # (10)
                           |  
          br 8                ( D )                     # (8)
             9                ( D )                     # (9)
                         )
          12             ( R )                     # (12)
          13             ( R )                     # (13)
                      |  
       br 4              ( B )                     # (4)
          5              ( B )                     # (5)
          6              ( B )                     # (6)
                      |  
       br 4              ( v )                     # (4)
                    )
     3         )                         # (3 end)
               r
   2      )                         # (2 end)
   14     ( o )                     # (14)
   15     ( i )                     # (15)
       |  
br 2      ( t )                     # (2)
          s
   3      ( w )                     # (3)
     )
16   ( Z )                     # (16)
```

---

***Addendum for Dot-Net counting***

There are 2 options for counting Dot-Net captures.

1. Count named capture groups
2. Named groups last

Obviously, without 1 you don't get 2.

Example: Don't count named groups

```
1    (                             # (1 start)
          (?'overall'
               ^
               (?= [^&] )
               (?:
                    (?<scheme> [^:/?#]+ )
                    :
               )?
               (?:
                    //
  2                 ( )                           # (2)
                    (?<authority> [^/?#]* )
               )?
               (?<path> [^?#]* )
               (?:
                    \?
                    (?<query> [^#]* )
               )?
  3            ( )                           # (3)
               (?:
                    \#
                    (?<fragment> .* )
               )?
          )
1    )                             # (1 end)
```

Example: Count named groups

```
1    (                             # (1 start)
  2       (?'overall'                   # (2 start)
               ^
               (?= [^&] )
               (?:
    3               (?<scheme> [^:/?#]+ )         # (3)
                    :
               )?
               (?:
                    //
    4               ( )                           # (4)
    5               (?<authority> [^/?#]* )       # (5)
               )?
    6          (?<path> [^?#]* )             # (6)
               (?:
                    \?
    7               (?<query> [^#]* )             # (7)
               )?
    8          ( )                           # (8)
               (?:
                    \#
    9               (?<fragment> .* )             # (9)
               )?
  2       )                             # (2 end)
1    )                             # (1 end)
```

Example: Count named groups, and Named groups last

```
1    (                             # (1 start)
  4       (?'overall'                   #_(4 start)         
               ^
               (?= [^&] )
               (?:
    5               (?<scheme> [^:/?#]+ )         #_(5)         
                    :
               )?
               (?:
                    //
    2               ( )                           # (2)
    6               (?<authority> [^/?#]* )       #_(6)         
               )?
    7          (?<path> [^?#]* )             #_(7)         
               (?:
                    \?
    8               (?<query> [^#]* )             #_(8)         
               )?
    3          ( )                           # (3)
               (?:
                    \#
    9               (?<fragment> .* )             #_(9)         
               )?
  4       )                             #_(4 end)         
1    )                             # (1 end)
```

Comment: None of the examples address my question. Nice try, though.

Comment: @Urhixidur - And, what was your question ?

Comment: "Are anonymous capturing groups absolutely or relatively numbered?" If one has a regex that mixes named and unnamed groups, will the numbered groups be numbered sequentially, or will the named groups "absorb" numbers? (Turns out it's the latter.) I'm probably not reading your example right (what are the regex and candidate strings you used?), but it did not seem to contain a mix of named and unnamed groups, just some convoluted conditionals.

Comment: @Urhixidur - I've added an addendum for Dot-Net regex, which I think is what you refer to. I just want to say, I've posted the _Rosetta Stone_ to decipher how _ALL_ regex engines count. All, it takes is to understand the numbers. To explain in extreme detail is useless and would take a book. It's not complicated, but it does, completely address your question.

Comment: @sIn - I didn't even know Dot-Net regex existed (Microsoft's .NET take on regex, I presume). My question cropped up while crafting a regex for Splunk, which uses PCRE. Your .NET example is confusing, as you state there are two options...and then proceed to show three.

Comment: @sIn - Back to the very first example you posted. Judging by the numbers in the left margin, it seems the regex is this monster:

( a )?( b )?( c )?(?(1)|(?(2)|(?(3)|(*FAIL))))(( a )?( b )?( c )?)(?(2)|(?(3)|(?(4)|(*FAIL))))(?<A> a )?(?<B> b )?(?<C> c )?(?(<A>)|(?(<B>)|(?(<C>) | (*FAIL) )))(?<M>(?<A> a )?(?<B> b )?(?<C> c )?(?(<A>)|(?(<B>)|(?(<C>) | (*FAIL) ))))

Looking at just the first part, ( a )?( b )?( c )?(?(1)|(?(2)|(?(3)|(*FAIL)))) we've got $1 which may match '' or ' a ', $2 for '' or ' b ', $3 for '' or ' c '.

Comment: @sIn - Next is a conditional pattern where the condition is '1', the then is empty, and the else is another conditional pattern. How wrong am I so far? I'm using http://help.dyalog.com/14.1/Content/Language/Appendices/PCRE%20Regular%20Expression%20Syntax%20Summary.htm for my syntax.

Comment: @Urhixidur - Its like any conditional. `If (not a) { if ( not b ) { if (not c) then FAIL } } }` where there is only need for 1 then. In other forms it's `if ( not a && not b && not c ) then FAIL` or `if ( not ( a || b || c ) ) then FAIL`, etc... The reason conditionals are added to the examples is to test the group counting behavior inside them. In your other question, the 3 Dot-Net options (for _named_ groups) are `1` No named-group counting, `1` Yes named-group counting, `1 & 2` Yes named group counting _AND_ count them last (after other groups).